# Qbs analogue of qmake system() command

Tags: qmake, qbs

in `qmake`, there is [`system()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command) function, which simply runs commands you pass at compile time. The question is: is there any `qbs` analogue of it? Qbs `Rule`/`Artifact` approach is designed for different purpose and is too verbose for simple use cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qmake's system() function does *not* run commands at compile time, but at configure time, which is different.

Please keep in mind that qmake and qbs are two very different build systems with fundamentally different designs and capabilities, and qbs' verbosity is in part due to its fundamental architectural differences which make it far more powerful than qmake will ever be capable of.

That said, the rough equivalent in qbs is the [Process](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/jsextension-process.html) service, which you can invoke from a Rule's outputArtifacts or prepare scripts, or from the right hand side of a property binding (although for performance reasons this is not recommended).

What exactly is your use case? You might be seeking the wrong mechanism in the first place...

Comment: It's like "I have some task/shell script to be done at compile time". It can be something like creating symlinks, requesting svn version, compressing app or whatever. `Rule`/`Artifact` approach requires input files which is not always the case. Also, sometimes it is important to put this task strictly before/after compilation

Comment: A specific use case is important. If your task needs to be run before or after compilation, then you should use the available mechanisms to hook into the build graph at the right point in time, by specifying proper dependencies. A system() equivalent is not a magic bullet that solves this problem outside the realm of the much more capable primitives provided. A task (Rule) *always* has inputs; if you think it doesn't then you can use the qbs source file itself (`inputs: ["qbs"]`) in order to ensure that the Rule is invoked.